# MYSQL join tables with same structure

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables (spentTime, estimatedTime, plannedTime), all with the same columns:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hours         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projectId     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projectName   | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
| userLogin     | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
| userFirstname | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |       |
| userLastname  | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to create a VIEW that represents the **sumed** spend-, planned-, and estimated-time for each couple (projectId;userId). That view should have that structure:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| spenthours    | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| estimatedhours| double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| plannedhours  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projectId     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projectName   | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
| userLogin     | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
| userFirstname | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |       |
| userLastname  | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I tried many combinaisons of join (with some StackOverFlow articles) but I cannot achieve what I want. Need some help.

Thanks

Comment: So uhm you have 3 tables without primary keys and only nullable fields? I'd recommend starting over...

Comment: Agree with @NielsKeurentjes, read up on primary and foreign keys and start it again.

Comment: Mh, I think I cannot do that. Those 3 tables are in fact 3 VIEWS and cannot modify them; they are used by other tools, so I can only read them to extract statistics…

Comment: Agreed a table with out a primary key constraint is almost always useless unless used for temporary data. I would suggest you first understand table normalization and choose the correct normal form for what you are trying to do. Then write the table structure following the constraints of the form. This will help you prevent getting bit by bad tables later on in the future. Even if your fooling around, always keep in mind, someone may want to use this for production. if that happens you need it to be maintanable.

Comment: I agree with that, for sure. But the fact is that I cannot modify the data source (the 3 views). So what would you suggest?

Comment: if you can't modify the views, use the tables these views get their data from